# Why is this convolution equation easier to apply than it's commutative counterpart?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolution, convolutional-neural-network

The convolution is an operation on two functions of a real- valued
argument.

The convolution operation is typically
denoted with an asterisk:

```
s(t) = (x ∗ w)(t)
```

It is a special kind of linear operation which is also commutative, so:

`s(t) = (x ∗ w)(t)` is also equal to `s(t) = (w ∗ x)(t)`.

In convolutional neural networks we usually use convolutions over multiple axis. In a  two-dimensional image we want to use 2 convolutional operations over two axis at a time. We also use a 2-D kernel as follows:

$S(i,j) =(I*K)(i,j)= \sum\limits_{m} \sum\limits_nI(m,n)K(i-m,j-n)$

where `I` is the input, and `K` is the Kernel.

It's commutative equivalent is:

$S(i,j) =(K*I)(i,j)= \sum\limits_{m} \sum\limits_nI(i-m,j-n)K(m,n)$

As per [www.deeplearningbook.org](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html),

> Usually the latter formula is more straightforward to implement in a machine
> learning library, because there is less variation in the range of valid values of
> m
> and n.

I am struggling to comprehend this sentence and thus, my question is, **why would there be less variation in the range of valid values of m and n when they are commutative equivalents**?

Comment: Kindly explain the reason when down voting. I will do my best to edit accordingly.